# I have a problem with arrows' tips in chemfig

Tags: arrows, chemfig, chemistry

Arrows' tips aren't in the accurate place, they are slightly shifted to the left. Does anyone have an idea how to fix it so that they could be in the middle?

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{chemformula}
    \usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
    \begin{document}
    \schemestart
        \chemfig{@{a1}Cl-[@{a2},.8]@{a3}\textcolor{red}{H}} 
        \+ 
        \chemfig{@{a4}\textcolor{blue}{\charge{0=\: , 180=\:}{O}}(-[:65,.6]H)-[:-65,.6]H} 
        \ch{<>} 
        \chemfig{\textcolor{blue}{\charge{0=\: , 125:3pt=\scriptsize $ \oplus $}{O}}(-[:65,.6]H)(-[:180,.6]\textcolor{red}{H})-[:-65,.6]H}
        \+
        \chemfig{\charge{25:3pt=\scriptsize $\ominus$}{Cl}}
    \schemestop
    \chemmove{
        \draw(a2)..controls +(85:4mm) and +(105:4mm)..(a1);
        \draw(a4.135)..controls +(100:4.5mm) and +(80:4.5mm)..(a3);}
    \end{document}
```

This is how it looks now.
[image]

Comment: Do you compile your code twice (at least)?  With up-to-date MikTeX installation I can't reproduce your problem, Try to upgrade your LaTeX installation.

Comment: You may also to consider to add `\usepackage{textgreek}` to your document preamble. BTW, it is not related to your problem, however i remove warnings during compilation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code wasn't bad when I compiled it in the latest version of latex (texlive 2023).

I adjusted some numbers on the arrows, and added some options.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\begin{document}
    \schemestart
    \chemfig{@{a1}Cl-[@{a2},.8]@{a3}\textcolor{red}{H}} 
    \+ 
    \chemfig{@{a4}\textcolor{blue}{\charge{0=\:,180=\:}{O}}(-[:65,.6]H)-[:-65,.6]H} 
    \ch{<>} 
    \chemfig{\textcolor{blue}{\charge{0=\: , 125:3pt=\scriptsize $ \oplus $}{O}}(-[:65,.6]H)(-[:180,.6]\textcolor{red}{H})-[:-65,.6]H}
    \+
    \chemfig{\charge{25:3pt=\scriptsize $\ominus$}{Cl}}
    \schemestop
    \chemmove{
        \draw[red,shorten <=1pt,shorten >=1pt](a2)..controls +(90:4mm) and +(80:6mm)..(a1);
        \draw[red,shorten <=3pt,shorten >=1pt](a4.180)..controls +(90:8mm) and +(80:5mm)..(a3);}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I compiled it in Overleaf Latex and indeed when I entered it into TexMaker it looked fine. I'm curious why this happened, is there an older version on Overleaf?

Comment: @MichałSzymankiewicz Overleaf does not yet have the current texlive versions. You can see the available versions in the sidebar. The newest one currently available there is texlive 2022, so more than a year old.

Answer (score 1):

As a slight variation of @CrocoDuck's nice answer: you could use a `to` path operation instead of Bézier curves to get arrows which look a bit more symmetric:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\begin{document}
    \schemestart
    \chemfig{@{a1}Cl-[@{a2},.8]@{a3}\textcolor{red}{H}} 
    \+ 
    \chemfig{@{a4}\textcolor{blue}{\charge{0=\:,180=\:}{O}}(-[:65,.6]H)-[:-65,.6]H} 
    \ch{<>} 
    \chemfig{\textcolor{blue}{\charge{0=\: , 125:3pt=\scriptsize $ \oplus $}{O}}(-[:65,.6]H)(-[:180,.6]\textcolor{red}{H})-[:-65,.6]H}
    \+
    \chemfig{\charge{25:3pt=\scriptsize $\ominus$}{Cl}}
    \schemestop
    \chemmove{
        \draw[red,shorten <=1pt,shorten >=1pt](a2) to [out=90,in=80,looseness=2.5] (a1);
        \draw[red,shorten <=3pt,shorten >=1pt](a4.180) to [out=100,in=80,looseness=1.5] (a3);}
\end{document}
```

[image]